# Intent to activity is not working while using fragment for card view on click

Tags: java, android, android-intent, fragment

I am using a `fragment` to hold **4 card views**, which should start a new activity on click. It can display the `toast` I generate which shows that the click function is working but it is unable to activate the intent.

I have tried using several names for the activity and also

```
Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), activity name.class)
```

code to start activity

```
package com.example.eb.ui.home;
import ...
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final CardView  java = root.findViewById(R.id.javacardId);
        final CardView  html = root.findViewById(R.id.htmlcardId);
        final CardView  c_prog = root.findViewById(R.id.C_cardId);
        final CardView  cpp = root.findViewById(R.id.cppcardId);
           //set on click listener
        java.setOnClickListener(this);
        html.setOnClickListener(this);
        cpp.setOnClickListener(this);
        c_prog.setOnClickListener(this);
             return root;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.javacardId :
                i = new Intent(this,html.class);
                startActivity(i);
                   break;
            case R.id.htmlcardId :
                i = new Intent(this,html_prog.class);
                startActivity(i);
                 break;
            case R.id.cppcardId :
                i = new Intent(this,cpp_prog.class);
               startActivity(i);
               break;
            case R.id.C_cardId :
                i = new Intent(this,c_prog.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            default: break;
        }

    }
}
---
```

I expect the **card view** in that `fragment` to open up new activity

Comment: Try initializing and setting the clicklistener in onViewCreated lifecycle method of Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "this" keyword to getContext()

```
  "i = new Intent(this,html.class);"
```

should be

```
  i = new Intent(getContext,html.class);
```

or initialize and set the clicklistener in onViewCreated() lifecycle method of Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use getActivity() instead of 'this' in a fragment for context like below.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.javacardId :
            i = new Intent(getActivity(),html.class);
            startActivity(i);
               break;
        default: break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter required by `Intent` is `Context`

As mentioned in the Android documentation ([Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E))):

```
packageContext  Context: A Context of the application package implementing this class.
```

Hence, you need to pass `getContext()` or `getActivity()` (since `Activity` extends `Context`) as follows:

```
i = new Intent(getActivity(), html.class);
startActivity(i);
```

I tried building and launching an app using your code (after making the change above) and it worked fine.

Comment: The problem probably lies somewhere else (in code not posted) then. This solution should technically work.